# unable to install anything via the terminal window on ubuntu 16.04 xenial xerus

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 just a couple of weeks back. Recently I started seeing a red error button on my notification shade on the top right saying

> An error occurred, please run package manager from the right click menu or apt-get in a terminal to see what is wrong.

The error message was:

```
Error opening the cache (E: type sudo is not known on line 55 source
list/etc.apt/sources.list,E: The list of sources could not be read).
This usually means your installed packages have unmet dependencies
```

How can I solve this?

I tried the suggested commands "ls -l /usr/bin/sudo" ,"sudo apt-get install -f"
and "sudo dpkg --confiure -a" as suggested .So here is my terminal output to the commands in form of this terminal screenshot. Please check the attached screenshot and help me further.
[terminal 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zesDT.png)

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the *full, verbatim* output of `ls -l /usr/bin/sudo` and `sudo apt-get install -f`? Thanks.

Comment: Please run `sudo dpkg --confiure -a` from terminal and lets see the output. Please copy the output and paste it into your question by adding after clicking the edit button

Comment: I have attached the result to the above commands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [sources.list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OokCh.png), you have to remove the bottom three lines in that file. Then run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -f install`

You can edit it using `gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list` - and just remove the bottom three lines (starting with sudo ...) and save the file again. Then run commands as above.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following steps you have mentioned above but have found no luck with success on that.Still returns with the same line 55 error in the source.list .Here is an attached screenshot of the terminal window.Have a look at it -

[error while installation via command window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImRr9.png)

Here is my sources.list attached please check it out

[sources.list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OokCh.png)

Comment: Please include the content of /etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: @vidarlo I have attached my content of /etc/apt/sources.list .Please check it out .I haven't been able to install anything via the command line all this time

Answer (score -1):

Okay follow these steps to fix it:

1. On keyboard type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>
2. In the terminal that opens type:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
3. Enter your password when asked, **please note as you enter you won't see it in the terminal** (that's the Linux way).
4. Now let it run till, after that type again in the terminal:

   ```
   sudo apt-get upgrade
   ```
5. Repeat `step 3`

ALTERNATIVELY:

1. Click on `dash` or <kbd>Super</kbd> key (on your keyboard) and type `terminal`

   [image]
2. Click on ther `terminal` application
3. In the terminal that opens type:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
4. Enter your password when asked, **please note as you enter you won't see it in the terminal** (that's the Linux way).
5. Now let it run till, after that type again in the terminal:

   ```
   sudo apt-get upgrade
   ```
6. Repeat `step 4`

If the red icon remains just ignore till reboot or reboot.

Comment: I was recommended the same by my friend but this hasnt helped me